# need to set default assets or images folder

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any solution to set default path for image sources for windows phone? Some manifest changes?

I want to write `<Image Source="img1.png" />` instead of `<Image Source="Assets/Images/img1.png" />`

Actually this feature will be extremely useful for xamarin developers. Now I need to create such a huge piece of code in xamarin studio:

```
<Image>
        <Image.Source>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                          <OnPlatform.iOS>
                            <FileImageSource File="img1.png"/>
                          </OnPlatform.iOS>
                          <OnPlatform.Android>
                            <FileImageSource File="img1.png"/>
                          </OnPlatform.Android>
                          <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                            <FileImageSource File="Assets/Images/img1.png"/>
                          </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                        </OnPlatform>
                      </Image.Source>
        </Image>
```

And my aim is to turn this code into `<Image Source="img1.png"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible for Windows Phone. If you want to use

```
 <Image Source="img1.png"/>
```

it is necessary that the image is at the root of the project.